# Disable GridViewColoum on Page_Load

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a Delete-Button in my gridview that i used to create with an TemplateField + LinkButton + OnRowCommand.

Now a normal user should not be able to use this button - or better not to see this button at all.

How to disable a coloumn in a gridView on the page Log event?

Comment: means you want gridview column disable on page_load for normal User?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this: column visible use before bind grid otherwise error occurring.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     gridView.DataSource = "yourDatasource";
     gridView.DataBind();
     gridView.Columns[ColumnIndex].Visible =false;
}
```

Comment: disable and visible are not the same thing

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

          // get the column here and your condition to make that disabled
         e.Row.Cells[index].Visible = false;

    }

  }
```

You can also hide like:

```
((DataControlField)gridView.Columns
               .Cast<DataControlField>()
               .Where(fld => (fld.HeaderText == "Title"))
               .SingleOrDefault()).Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In your `Page_Load`

```
GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

then column 0 of the grid become disable and the other column of the grid resize automatically.